# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'String.Element' (aka 'Character')

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to solve a challenge but i have a problem in a part

```
func inArray(_ a1: [String], _ a2: [String]) -> [String] {
    var result: [String] = []
    outer: for i in 0..<a1.count {
        for j in 0..<a2.count {
            if a2[i].contains(a1[j]) {
                result.append(a1[j])
                continue outer
            }
        }
    }
    return result.sorted(by: >)  
}
```

but appear a error in this line

```
if a2[i].contains(a1[j]) {
```

the error is:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'String.Element' (aka 'Character')
```

Comment: `a2[i]` is a `String`. `a1[j]` is a `String`. There is no method `contains` That has type `(String) -> Bool`. The one you're calling take a character, and checks if the string contains that character. Are you trying to see if `a1[j]` is a substring of `a2[i]`?

Comment: Read. The. Error. Message.

Comment: There is no error in your code. You just have to build it again. Also fix any other compiler error that could be the reason `Xcode` incorrectly pointing to this.

Comment: yes, i want to see if a1[j] is a substring of a2[i], but i could not do it

Comment: your code is perfectly OK, even than please show the data your array contains.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that you have import the foundation framework in your code file.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of **`filter(_:)`** and **`contains(where:)`** to solve the problem statement, i.e.

```
func inArray(_ a1: [String], _ a2: [String]) -> [String] {
    return a1.filter({ (str) in
        a2.contains(where: { $0.contains(str) })
    }).sorted(by: >)
}
```

**Example:**

```
let x = inArray(["ab", "cd", "ef"], ["xyzabpqr", "qwerty", "acdfg"])
print(x) //["cd", "ab"]
```

Comment: Why don't you simply filter a1? `a1.filter { str in a2.contains { $0.contains(str) } }.sorted(by: >)`